# Как удалять файлы в папке с определённым размером python

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, файлы

Помогите, есть папка, где куча неправильных изображений с единым размером.
как сделать так, чтобы при запуске python скрипта эти файлы удалялись?

Answer (score 1):

Так можно, размер в байтах указан:

```
import os
path = 'path/to/fold'
for item in os.listdir(path):
    size = os.path.getsize(f'{path}/{item}')
    if size == 7161:
        os.remove(f'{path}/{item}')
```

Comment: А можно как-то в КБ

Comment: ну разделите на 1024, Дмитрий :)

Comment: поделите на 1024, но не факт что совпадет , тогда лучше округлять оба значения, если это возможно в вашем случае и не навредит остальным файлам